# Select distinct values from db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, localhost

I have two tables

user:

```
id,
username
```

and

app:

```
userid,
appid,
mainid
```

I want to display users that dont have a record in this table.I get from address `mainId` and `appid`.If I run this query

```
SelectQuery("select  User.UserName
from User
INNER JOIN App
ON User.Id = App.UserId
where App.Mainid!= ".$var_MainId." and App.AppId<>".$var_AppId);
```

It doesnt show the users that may have same `userid` and `mainid` but not same `appid`

Comment: Sample data, current output, and expected output would help a lot here

Comment: If I do the following query `where App.Mainid= ".$var_MainId." and App.AppId =".$var_AppId);` it shows only one user(correct) from two users that I have in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `not exists` clause.  For example, to find users who don't have an app entry with MainId 123 and AppId 456:

```
select  u.UserName
from    User u
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    App a
        where   a.UserId = u.Id
                and a.MainId = 123
                and a.AppId = 456
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an anti-join pattern. But the specification isn't very clear. (Sample data and expected output would go a long ways towards clarifying it.)

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.username
  FROM user u
  LEFT
  JOIN app a
    ON a.userid = u.id
   AND a.mainid <=> ?
   AND a.appid  <=> ?
 WHERE a.userid IS NULL
```

This query will return rows from `u` where there is not a matching row in `a` that has the specified values for mainid and appid.

Given contents of `user` table as

```
  id  username
----  --------
   2  foo
   3  fee
   5  fi
```

and `app` table as

```
userid   appid   mainid 
------   -----   ------
     2     444      888
     3     444        1
     3       1      888
```

if we specify a value of 444 for `appid` and 888 for `mainid` in the query, e.g.

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.username
  FROM user u
  LEFT
  JOIN app a
    ON a.userid = u.id
   AND a.mainid <=> 444
   AND a.appid  <=> 888
 WHERE a.userid IS NULL
```

this query would return users 3 and 5. (User 2 will not be returned, because there is a row in `app` that matches the specification.)

---

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. Using a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` pattern is probably the easiest pattern to understand.

Comment: even your solution works,however I can accept only one and I cant give you a +1 since my score is less than 15 but thanks anyway

Comment: @RandomUser:  if you run EXPLAIN on the query in my answer, and the query in Andomar's answer, and compare, the two execution plans will likely be very similar... we expect the EXPLAIN for the query in my answer will show "Not exists" in the Extra column. If NULL values aren't a concern, then feel free to replace the `<=>` (spaceship) null-safe comparison operator with plain old equality `=` comparison operator.